# Best way to store tokens in Next.js for authentication

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, authorization, csrf

I am working on a Next.js application and implementing authentication using tokens. I have three tokens: accessToken, refreshToken (both are jwt and contain userId, email and role), and csrfToken (cryptographically random 32 digit character string). I would like to know the best practices for storing these tokens securely in my Next.js application. Here is my current approach, and I would appreciate feedback and suggestions on whether this is the recommended way or if there are better alternatives.

My suggestion is to store the refreshToken in a secure, HTTP-only cookie. This approach ensures that the token is protected from cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks and cannot be accessed by JavaScript.

As for the accessToken and csrfToken, I plan to receive them as a response from the login POST request and then store them in Next.js using a context provider. By doing this, I can easily access these tokens across different components and pages within my application.

Is this approach recommended? Are there any potential security risks or drawbacks that I should be aware of? Are there any alternative methods that are considered best practices for storing tokens in a Next.js application? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) article provides some up to date best practices. Secure values cannot be stored entirely safely in the browser. Section 6.2 describes a backend for frontend approach that is commonly used these days.

Extra attack vectors around XSS concerns and token interception mean that HTTP-only cookie based security is perceived to be safer, and threats better understood, when data requests are sent.

A solid approach is to store all OAuth tokens in the latest `HTTP-only SameSite=strict` cookies. The CSRF token is a secondary value which can be stored in memory or even local storage. If it is exfiltrated from the browser it does not provide access to secured data.

With cookies, XSS remains a concern. For any browser based app with XSS vulnerabilities, malicious code can do anything your app can do, eg send the cookie to the backend. Therefore also follow OWASP XSS best practices, including a [Content Security Policy](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.html), which can help to mitigate data exfiltration risks.

Comment: What steps should I take to secure the initial request when the CSRF cookie is generated on the server side? Specifically, when making a request to the login endpoint for the first time and there is no token available.

Comment: Follow what a website does, which is to call the token endpoint with an authorization code, a PKCE code verifier, and a client secret. Once the website receives tokens it can return CSRF values to the browser. The browser client can then send CSRF values in data changing API requests. Eg use the [double submit cookie pattern](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-in-depth-techniques) from the OWASP docs. Issuing a CSRF value after authentication should be sufficient, so that it can be shared across browser tabs.